# Pattern matching with streams in Racket?

Tags: stream, pattern-matching, racket

Pattern matching is a very readable alternative to manual destructuring in let clauses. I was wondering whether it's possible to use it with streams, like we can with lists.

As an illustration, consider a simple `add-between` implementation to produce a sequence with an element inserted between each of the elements of the original sequence.

```
(define (add-between lst sep)
  (match lst
    ['() '()]
    [(cons v vs)
     (cons v
           (cons sep
                 (add-between vs sep)))]))
```

Usage:

```
(add-between (list 'a 'b 'c) 'and) ; => '(a and b and c and)
```

What if we want to do the same with arbitrary sequences, like streams?

```
(define (add-between seq sep)
  (match seq
    ['() '()]
    [(cons v vs)
     (stream-cons v
                  (stream-cons sep
                               (add-between vs sep)))]))
```

This produces an error:

```
(add-between (stream 'a 'b 'c) 'and)
; match: no matching clause for #<stream>
; stdin:1:1
; Context:
;  /Applications/Racket v7.5/collects/racket/match/runtime.rkt:24:0 match:error
;  /Applications/Racket v7.5/collects/racket/repl.rkt:11:26
```

It would be ideal if we could pattern match on a generic sequence type, since that would encapsulate lists as well as streams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own pattern-matching forms for streams, using `define-match-expander`, `?` with predicates, and `app` with accessors.

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse/define (prefix-in * racket/stream))
(define (stream-empty? v) (and (stream? v) (*stream-empty? v)))
(define (stream-cons? v) (and (stream? v) (not (*stream-empty? v))))

(define-match-expander stream-cons
  (syntax-parser
    [(_ fst rst) #'(? stream-cons? (app stream-first fst) (app stream-rest rst))])
  (syntax-parser
    [(_ fst rst) #'(*stream-cons fst rst)]))

(define-match-expander stream*
  (syntax-parser
    [(_ rst) #'rst]
    [(_ fst more ... rst) #'(stream-cons fst (stream* more ... rst))])
  (syntax-parser
    [(_ init ... rst) #'(*stream* init ... rst)]))

(define-match-expander stream
  (syntax-parser
    [(_) #'(? stream-empty?)]
    [(_ elem ...) #'(stream* elem ... (? stream-empty?))])
  (syntax-parser
    [(_ elem ...) #'(*stream elem ...)]))
```

Using it:

```
> (define (add-between seq sep)
    (match seq
      [(stream) (stream)]
      [(stream-cons v vs)
       (stream-cons v
                    (stream-cons sep
                                 (add-between vs sep)))]))
> (add-between (stream 'a 'b 'c) 'and)
#<stream>
> (stream->list (add-between (stream 'a 'b 'c) 'and))
'(a and b and c and)
```

Comment: Being able to extend match patterns sounds perfect. Your code above would work for streams specifically, but seems like it should be straightforward to modify it to support arbitrary sequences, e.g. either racket sequences or data/collection sequences. This is great!

Comment: I'm not sure about arbitrary sequences. Streams work so well because they are based on a `cons`-like structure just like normal lists, and not all sequences would be as convenient to do pattern-matching for

Answer (score 3):

@[AlexKnauth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5432501/alex-knauth)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60570617/849891) is illuminating. I've since also discovered that the `data/collection` library provides a [built-in way](https://docs.racket-lang.org/collections/collections-api.html#%28part._.Using_sequences_with_match%29) to do this for arbitrary sequences (that is, sequences as defined [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/collections/collections-api.html#%28part._.Sequences%29)). Using this match pattern, the code in the question could be written for generic sequences as:

```
(require data/collection)

(define (add-between seq sep)
  (match seq
    [(sequence) empty-stream]
    [(sequence v vs ...)
     (stream-cons v
                  (stream-cons sep
                               (add-between vs sep)))]))
```

Using it:

```
(sequence->list (add-between (stream 'a 'b 'c) 'and))
=> '(a and b and c and)

(sequence->string (add-between "hello" #\space))
"h e l l o "
```

Comment: we probably need one more nested match to prevent adding the `sep` before the empty stream. same with the lists in the question. but that's just details, of course.

Comment: @WillNess you mean to handle the singleton case, so that `(add-between '(1) 'a) => '(1)` rather than `'(1 a)`? Yeah, we'd need an additional `(sequence v) (stream v)` base case for that.